# Phonegap: Error "Class Contacts cannot be found" in BlackBerry 10

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I get this error when my application calls:

```js
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

The onError callback ---> *Class Contacts cannot be found.*

I think that it may be a problem with the plugin configuration. In my plugins.xml I have this line:

```xml
<plugin name="Contacts"       value="org.apache.cordova.pim.Contact"/>
```

and the config.xml:

```xml
<feature id="blackberry.identity" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
<feature id="blackberry.pim.Address" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
<feature id="blackberry.pim.Contact" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
```

I'm building with Phonegap 2.7.0, and I have followed the [api guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts).
And deploying to BB10 simulator.

I don't know what's the configuration problem with 'Contacts', any idea?

EDIT: This is my config.xml for BB10

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  Widget Configuration Reference:
    http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/15274/
-->

<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
        version="1.0.0.0"
        id="com.xxxxx.xxxx">

  <name>xxxx</name>

  <author href="http://www.xxxxx.es" email="info@xxxxx.es">
        xxxxx
  </author>

  <description>
       xxxxx description.
  </description>

  <license href="http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical">
  </license>

  <!-- Cordova API -->
  <feature id="blackberry.system" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="org.apache.cordova" required="true" version="1.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.find" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.identity" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.identity.phone" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.pim.Address" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.pim.Contact" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.io.file" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.utils" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.io.dir" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.app.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <feature id="blackberry.system.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.widgetcache" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.media.camera" />
  <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" />
  <feature id="blackberry.connection" />
  <feature id="blackberry.bbm.platform" />
  <feature id="blackberry.invoke.card" />
  <feature id="blackberry.pim.contacts" />
  <feature id="blackberry.ui.contextmenu" />
  <feature id="blackberry.io.filetransfer" />
  <feature id="blackberry.io" />
  <feature id="blackberry.invoke" />
  <feature id="blackberry.invoked" />
  <feature id="blackberry.push" />
  <feature id="blackberry.media.microphone" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>

  <!-- Cordova API -->
  <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///store/home" />
  <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///SDCard" />

  <!-- Expose access to all URIs, including the file and http protocols -->

  <access uri="*" subdomains="true" />
  <access uri="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true"/>
  <access uri="http://debug.build.phonegap.com" subdomains="true"/>
  <access uri="http://xxxxx.com" subdomains="true"/>

  <!--
  <icon rim:hover="false" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
  <icon rim:hover="true" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
  -->
  <icon rim:hover="false" src="res/icon/blackberry/windows_phone_62x62.png" />
  <icon rim:hover="true" src="res/icon/blackberry/windows_phone_62x62.png" />

  <rim:loadingScreen backgroundColor="#CFCFCF"
                     foregroundImage="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"
             onFirstLaunch="true">
    <rim:transitionEffect type="fadeOut" />
  </rim:loadingScreen>

  <content src="index.html" />

  <rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>use_camera</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>record_audio</rim:permit> 
    <rim:permit>access_pimdomain_contacts</rim:permit> 
  </rim:permissions>


</widget>
```

Comment: Can you post your full config.xml ?

Comment: I just added to my post. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, did find a solution to this. I have the same predicament. When I set a breakpoint in the source code where the exception occured I find that cordova loaded only the following plugins **(NetworkStatus, Accelerometer, Device, Battery, Compass, Camera, Capture, Logger, Notification, Media, File, InAppBrowser, FileTransfer)**

Answer (score 0):

THe feature ID you are using is for the older versions of the BlackBerry OS. Please use `<feature id="blackberry.pim.contacts" />`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my config.xml already includes that entry. I have tried to comment the "Contact" entry too.